# mult-colored multirow tables (not using \multirow{-x})

Tags: tables, color, multirow, rowcolor

I wonder if there's a different way to do the alternate colors in a multirow tables.
Everywhere people use "\multirow{-x}"  but i would like to know if there's a way of doing it without any negative numbers and preferably not writing row by row.
i'd like a table like this: [image: i'd like a table like this]

```
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\centering
\caption{Multirow table with all cells in the same color.}\label{tab:multi row}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2\\
\hline
-&-\\
-&-\\
\cellcolor{lightgray}&Single-row\\
\cellcolor{lightgray}&Single-row\\
\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor{lightgray}Multi-row (3)}&Single-row\\
-&-\\
-&-\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%
```

(not my code, got it here: https://texblog.org/2014/05/19/coloring-multi-row-tables-in-latex/)

Comment: You should have a look at the package `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, a) the `\multirow` command spans an odd number of rows and b) the text in the multirow spans a single row, you can use something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}
\centering
\caption{Multirow table with all cells in the same color.}\label{tab:multi row}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2\\
\hline
- & - \\
- & - \\
 & Single-row \\
\cellcolor{lightgray}Multi-row (3) & Single-row \\
 & Single-row \\
- & - \\
- & - \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do taht with the latest version of `nicematrix` (v. 5.3 of 2020-09-03).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\centering
\caption{Multirow table with all cells in the same color.}\label{tab:multi row}
\begin{NiceTabular}{p{5cm}p{5cm}}[code-before = \rowcolors{1}{}{lightgray}]
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2\\
\hline
- & - \\
- & - \\
\Block[l,fill=lightgray]{3-1}{Multi-row (3)} & Single-row \\
 & Single-row \\
 & Single-row \\
- & - \\
- & - \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]